# how to use listView with parsed strings in Android?

Tags: android, listview

Here is my code. I want to see these parsed strings into ListView in Android. How can I do this?

```
    DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlRecords));

    Document doc = db.parse(is);
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
      Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

      NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("name");
      Element line = (Element) name.item(0);
      System.out.println("Name: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));

      NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("title");
      line = (Element) title.item(0);
      System.out.println("Title: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
    }

  }


       public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
        Node child = e.getFirstChild();
        if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
          CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
          return cd.getData();
        }
        return "";
      }
    }
```

Comment: Create a `ListView`. Create an `Adapter` for your Strings. Assign your `Adapter` to the `ListView`... An example: [link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/)